# Having trouble using Structures and Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am programming in C.
Considering the following Code.

My structure is defined as:

```
// Define the stack
struct stackNode {
char data;
struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef StackNode *StackNodePtr;
```

The following Variables are used:

```
StackNode topTracker; // The pointer of this stackNode will always point to the top of the stack
```

And I am trying to complete the following function.

```
char pop( StackNodePtr *topPtr ){
    char returnable;
// store the Node.data from the top of the stack
    returnable = *topPtr.data; //[1]
// Set the next Node to the top of the stack
    topTracker.nextPtr = *topPtr.nextPtr; //[2]
// return the Node data.
    return returnable;
```

The problem is I get the following error: at Point [1] & [2] respectively

"request for member `data' in something not a structure or union"
"request for member`nextPtr' in something not a structure or union"

How do I get around this error and actually access the data and nextPtr of the pointer *topPtr? Given that *topPtr will be a pointer to an actual StackNode at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`topPtr` is of type `StackNodePtr*` which is an alias for `StackNode**`. This means that `*topPtr` is of type `StackNode*` which is a pointer type and you must access the members using `->`.

Also beware that the operators `.` and `->` bind stronger than unary `*`. You therefore have to use parenthesis to manipulate the evaluation order:

```
returnable = (*topPtr)->data;
```

or

```
returnable = (**topPtr).data;
```

Comment: returnable = (*topPtr)->data;

Thats the one that did it. Applied that logic throughout my stack and it is now functional. Thank you. Oswald.

Answer (score 1):

`*topPtr` gives a `StackNodePtr`. 
which is still one level away from the structure.
you need to dereference it once again to get StackNode.
`(**topPtr)` will give the StackNode.

use `(**topPtr).data` or `(*Ptr)->data` to get to the structure member.

Comment: Cheers Alvin, A similar reply as Oswalds answer and will mark this as correct also.

Answer (score -1):

u r using wrong syntax it shud be topPtr->data.
Also if u need to learn, learn now about memory leaks.
It is there in ur above program.
so as soon as u retrieve ur data free the memory 
Eg.
returnable = topPtr->data;
StackNodePtr *tmp = topPtr;
topTracker->nextPtr = topPtr->nextPtr;
free(tmp);
return returnable;

Comment: Thanks Nik, its a rushed project due for a hand in today - and my knowledge of C is limited.

Before I move deeper into C I will learn how to manage my memory and garbage but for now it will do. :)

Thanks.